# Magento simple product not linked to configurable

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'have got an issue with my magento [V1.9.3.6]
Currently when i try to add a product to cart ( configurable product with associated simples ) their is a problem.

On my back i can't see the product associated to the configurable.

[image: view from product backend]

In the Db `catalog_product_relation`, there are no data for this product.
But in the `catalog_product_super_link`:

[image: Superlink db]

there are the super attribute relation.
Either i can't add them from the back since i don't find them even by ID.

If anyone had this issue and know how to deal with it, you'r welcome.

Comment: Do you have any error when you try to add the product in cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find your simple products in the search of the associated products (img 1), I think that your simple are not well configurated.

Please check your simple products and check if attributes 'couleur' and 'taille' are well setted

Comment: Thx for your answers, after the check you suggest it seems like our super attribute on simple product wasn't set properly